# Find out what Backbone "router" is actually getting

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events, backbone-routing

Trying to get a backbone router to work. Having one of those situations where nothing is happening so its difficult to pinpoint the problem.

Is there a way to find out what the Router is actually receiving so that I can try to pinpoint the problem with my routes?

This is the code so far:

```
// ROUTER
var TheRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    // ROUTES
    routes: {
        "":               "main",
        "/route1/:key":   "route1"

    },
    // INITIALIZE
    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this);
    },

    // ROUTES
    main: function(){
        alert('main');
    },

    route1: function(key){
        alert(key);
    }

});

// Create new router
var theRouter = new TheRouter();
// Start history
Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});
```

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind to the `route` event on the `Backbone.history`. According to the [source code](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-113) you get all the info going into the router from that event, meaning you should be able to `console.log` it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the slash from the beginning of your second route.
So the

```
    "/route1/:key":   "route1"
```

line becomes

```
    "route1/:key":   "route1"
```

If you are still getting no feedback, make sure you defined your dependent scripts in the correct order (jquery.js, underscore.js, backbone.js, yourRouter.js).